# Watson Discovery "Access is denied due to invalid credentials" - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I want to use IBM Watson Discovery Services but I am receiving an error message when trying to.
The error message is: `WatsonException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials`

```
import sys  
import os  
import json  
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1  

discovery = DiscoveryV1(  
    username="{bbbaaaaa}",  
    password="{aaaaaabbbb}",  
    version="2017-09-01"
)  

qopts = {'query': 'enriched_text.entities.text:IBM'}  
my_query = discovery.query('system', 'news', qopts)  
print(json.dumps(my_query, indent=2))
```

Comment: FYI, if those are actual Discovery credentials, I highly recommend removing or changing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `{` and the `}` from your username and password.

It should now be

```
discovery = DiscoveryV1(  
    username="aaaaabbbbbb",  
    password="bbbbbaaaaa",  
    version="2017-09-01"
)
```

Comment: Right sir.. Simple solution but I Find answer from 2 days